# Add a new property inside object without directly adding it?

Tags: javascript, object, object-literal

I have this code:

```
var a = {
 b: "Hello",
 c: "Foo",
 d: "Bar"
};

if(a["b"]) {
  // this code will add a new property inside the object a
}
```

How can I add a new property without directly adding it inside the `a` object? I mean, adding a new property inside it after the object's being created? Something like this.

```
function addNewPropertyInsideObject(obj,propname,propvalue) {
 // some code here
}

var a = {
 b: "Hello",
 c: "Foo",
 d: "Bar"
};

addNewPropertyInsideObject(a, e, "Baz"); // this code will add a new property with the name "e" & value "Baz" inside the object "a"
```

Comment: `obj[propname] = propvalue;`

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do this? What is it that you're trying to achieve that can't be done by "adding a new property directly"? It's very hard to offer useful suggestions without really understanding that.

Comment: obj[propname]= propvalue;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as that

```
function addNewPropertyInsideObject(obj,propname,propvalue) {
   obj[propname] = propvalue;
   return obj;
}
```

Comment: It also would be helpful if you have shown how to invoke it (since their code is slightly incorrect)